# How do I add an image and a label to a tab bar item with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Using this code I can set the label or the image but am unclear how to set both.

```
    var body: some View {
        Text("Library")
            .font(.title)
//            .tabItemLabel(Image("first"))
            .tabItemLabel(Text("Library"))
            .tag(0)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>In the SwiftUI Essentials WWDC talk, they use this sample code to have both image and label in tab bar item:</del>

```
TabbedView { 
  OrderForm()
  .tabItemLabel {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
    Text("New Order")
  }
  OrderHistory()
  .tabItemLabel {
    Image(systemName: "clock.fill")
    Text("History")
  }
}
```




<del>But at this moment using this approach to add `tabItemLabel` in Xcode 11 beta throws a compiler error and it cannot be used. So it might be a bug and will probably fix in next releases.</del>

---

### Update:

This issue was fixed with **Xcode 11 beta 3**. `tabItemLabel` is renamed to `tabItem` and can be used like below:

```
.tabItem {
    Image(systemName: "circle")
    Text("Tab1")
}
```

Comment: Do you know when new beta releases are normally expected for Xcode? Are they released at the same time of every iOS 13 beta update?

Comment: @ThomasVos I'm not sure, but I think it's released about the same time. Previous Xcode beta release notes might be available to check and estimate.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround on the officially [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_2_release_notes) of iOS 13 Beta 2:

> Workaround: Wrap the views you pass to the modifier in a VStack:

```
MyView()
    .tabItemLabel(VStack {
        Image("resourceName")
        Text("Item")
    })
```

Note: this workaround does not work with `Image(systemImage: "")`

Comment: Note: this workaround does not work with Image(systemImage: "")

Comment: Thanks, I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Label](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/label) in iOS 14.0+

```
.tabItem {
    Label("First Tab", systemImage: "phone.fill")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that Xcode 11 GM has been released, here's how you can implement a [TabView](https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/swiftui/tabview-swiftui) item, with images & labels

```swift
.tabItem {
   Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
   Text("First Tab")
}
```